# How come I am unable to get the output for tax for my code?

Tags: php, html

Write a function to compute the discount and tax when you pay for a shopping items in a shop.
Discount is 20% if the total order > $200, else the discount is 0.
Tax is 7% of the total order after discount.

```
<?php
            function computeDiscountAndTax($discount, $tax){
                $totalOrder = 100;
                if ($totalOrder > 200){
                    $discount = ($discount/100) * $totalOrder;
                    $tax = ($tax/100) * ($totalOrder - $discount);
                    return array($discount, $tax);
                } else {
                    $tax = ($tax/100) * $totalOrder;
                }
            }

            $result_array = computeDiscountAndTax(0, 7);
            echo "Discount: " . $result_array[0] . "<br>";
            echo "Tax: " . $result_array[1] . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: You don't return anything if `$totalOrder <= 200` . You should have told us about the undefined index warning you get with this code

Comment: that function argument is confusing, the arguments should be total order, then you compute for discount and tax and return it both in a form of array. it feels like an assignment or from an exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're not returning anything after `else`. You set `tax` to equal something, but you don't return it.

The following will get you the output that you're expecting.

```
<?php
function computeDiscountAndTax($discount, $tax){
            $totalOrder = 100;
            if ($totalOrder > 200){
                    $discount = ($discount/100) * $totalOrder;
                    $tax = ($tax/100) * ($totalOrder - $discount);
                    return array($discount, $tax);
            } else {
                    return array(0, ($tax/100) * $totalOrder);
            }
        }

        $result_array = computeDiscountAndTax(10, 7);
        echo "Discount: " . $result_array[0] . "<br />";
        echo "Tax: " . $result_array[1] . "<br />";
```

However, it should be noted, there is a lot odd about what you're doing. Why is the total hard-coded inside the function? Why are you returning the values as non-associative array? This has the potential of getting really confusing really fast.

I'd recommend doing something like this.

```
<?php
function computeDiscountAndTax($order, $discount, $tax){
            $tax = ($tax/100) * ($order - $discount);
            $discount = $order > 200 ? ($discount/100) * $order : 0;
            return ["discount" => $discount, "tax" => $tax];
        }

        $results = computeDiscountAndTax(100, 10, 7);
        echo "Discount: " . $results['discount'] . "<br />";
        echo "Tax: " . $results['tax'] . "<br />";
```